# Keep the first (newest) records from a powershell dataset based on one column's value

Tags: powershell, sorting, dataset, unique

I have a dataset that looks like this:

[Starting situation:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dc55q.png)

| MsgNr | State | DateTime | Ms | TimeDiff | Typename | Type | Text2 | Text1 | AlarmTag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 800292 | 2 | 2/16/2024 9:05:57 AM | 692 | 6344 | Error | 1 | =80+80.25.08-B208.6 | Photo eye blocked | 12231 |
| 800249 | 2 | 2/16/2024 9:05:57 AM | 692 | 68 | Error | 1 | =80+80.11.07-B118.5 | Photo eye blocked | 12175 |
| 800226 | 2 | 2/16/2024 9:05:57 AM | 692 | 3882 | Error | 1 | =80+80.03.08-B104.6 | Photo eye blocked | 12152 |
| 800249 | 1 | 2/16/2024 9:04:48 AM | 773 | 0 | Error | 1 | =80+80.11.07-B118.5 | Photo eye blocked | 12175 |
| 93004869 | 2 | 2/16/2024 8:52:29 AM | 685 | 154 | Error | 1 | IFZ-0030.14 | Infeed must be emptied | 21924 |
| 93004794 | 2 | 2/16/2024 8:52:29 AM | 678 | 154 | Error | 1 | BJ-0030.14.09 | Speed difference | 21908 |
| 805052 | 2 | 2/16/2024 8:52:15 AM | 395 | 2 | Maintenance | 2 | =80+80.11.07-M1 | Manual mode | 11586 |
| 805051 | 2 | 2/16/2024 8:52:15 AM | 395 | 2 | Maintenance | 2 | =80+80.11.06-M1 | Manual mode | 11585 |
| 805049 | 2 | 2/16/2024 8:52:15 AM | 395 | 2 | Maintenance | 2 | =80+80.11.04-M1 | Manual mode | 11583 |
| 805048 | 2 | 2/16/2024 8:52:15 AM | 395 | 2 | Maintenance | 2 | =80+80.11.03-M1 | Manual mode | 11582 |
| 805050 | 2 | 2/16/2024 8:52:15 AM | 395 | 2 | Maintenance | 2 | =80+80.11.05-M1 | Manual mode | 11584 |
| 805052 | 1 | 2/16/2024 8:52:13 AM | 210 | 0 | Maintenance | 2 | =80+80.11.07-M1 | Manual mode | 11586 |
| 805051 | 1 | 2/16/2024 8:52:13 AM | 210 | 0 | Maintenance | 2 | =80+80.11.06-M1 | Manual mode | 11585 |
| 805050 | 1 | 2/16/2024 8:52:13 AM | 210 | 0 | Maintenance | 2 | =80+80.11.05-M1 | Manual mode | 11584 |
| 805049 | 1 | 2/16/2024 8:52:13 AM | 210 | 0 | Maintenance | 2 | =80+80.11.04-M1 | Manual mode | 11583 |
| 805048 | 1 | 2/16/2024 8:52:13 AM | 210 | 0 | Maintenance | 2 | =80+80.11.03-M1 | Manual mode | 11582 |
| 93004869 | 1 | 2/16/2024 8:49:54 AM | 845 | 0 | Error | 1 | IFZ-0030.14 | Infeed must be emptied | 21924 |
| 93004794 | 1 | 2/16/2024 8:49:54 AM | 845 | 0 | Error | 1 | BJ-0030.14.09 | Speed difference | 21908 |
| 720669 | 2 | 2/16/2024 8:20:27 AM | 470 | 40 | Error | 1 | =72+72.04.71-WE1 | General error weighing scale | 8902 |
| 720669 | 1 | 2/16/2024 8:19:46 AM | 748 | 0 | Error | 1 | =72+72.04.71-WE1 | General error weighing scale | 8902 |

I want to keep the latest "State" of the "MsgNr" values.
So my script needs to look at all the rows from newest to oldest ("DateTime") and keep only the ones where "MsgNr" is unique.

[Result after `Sort-Object -Property MsgNr -Unique`:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8CfX.png)

| MsgNr | State | DateTime | Ms | TimeDiff | Typename | Type | Text2 | Text1 | AlarmTag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 720669 | 1 | 2/16/2024 8:19:46 | 748 | 0 | Error | 1 | =72+72.04.71-WE1 | General error weighing scale | 8902 |
| 800226 | 2 | 2/16/2024 9:05:57 | 692 | 3882 | Error | 1 | =80+80.03.08-B104.6 | Photo eye blocked | 12152 |
| 800249 | 2 | 2/16/2024 9:05:57 | 692 | 68 | Error | 1 | =80+80.11.07-B118.5 | Photo eye blocked | 12175 |
| 800292 | 2 | 2/16/2024 9:05:57 | 692 | 6344 | Error | 1 | =80+80.25.08-B208.6 | Photo eye blocked | 12231 |
| 805048 | 1 | 2/16/2024 8:52:13 | 210 | 0 | Maintenance | 2 | =80+80.11.03-M1 | Manual mode | 11582 |
| 805049 | 2 | 2/16/2024 8:52:15 | 395 | 2 | Maintenance | 2 | =80+80.11.04-M1 | Manual mode | 11583 |
| 805050 | 1 | 2/16/2024 8:52:13 | 210 | 0 | Maintenance | 2 | =80+80.11.05-M1 | Manual mode | 11584 |
| 805051 | 1 | 2/16/2024 8:52:13 | 210 | 0 | Maintenance | 2 | =80+80.11.06-M1 | Manual mode | 11585 |
| 805052 | 2 | 2/16/2024 8:52:15 | 395 | 2 | Maintenance | 2 | =80+80.11.07-M1 | Manual mode | 11586 |
| 93004794 | 2 | 2/16/2024 8:52:29 | 678 | 154 | Error | 1 | BJ-0030.14.09 | Speed difference | 21908 |
| 93004869 | 1 | 2/16/2024 8:49:54 | 845 | 0 | Error | 1 | IFZ-0030.14 | Infeed must be emptied | 21924 |

[My desired result would be:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gewZm.png)

| MsgNr | State | DateTime | Ms | TimeDiff | Typename | Type | Text2 | Text1 | AlarmTag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 800292 | 2 | 2/16/2024 9:05:57 | 692 | 6344 | Error | 1 | =80+80.25.08-B208.6 | Photo eye blocked | 12231 |
| 800249 | 2 | 2/16/2024 9:05:57 | 692 | 68 | Error | 1 | =80+80.11.07-B118.5 | Photo eye blocked | 12175 |
| 800226 | 2 | 2/16/2024 9:05:57 | 692 | 3882 | Error | 1 | =80+80.03.08-B104.6 | Photo eye blocked | 12152 |
| 93004869 | 2 | 2/16/2024 8:52:29 | 685 | 154 | Error | 1 | IFZ-0030.14 | Infeed must be emptied | 21924 |
| 93004794 | 2 | 2/16/2024 8:52:29 | 678 | 154 | Error | 1 | BJ-0030.14.09 | Speed difference | 21908 |
| 805052 | 2 | 2/16/2024 8:52:15 | 395 | 2 | Maintenance | 2 | =80+80.11.07-M1 | Manual mode | 11586 |
| 805051 | 2 | 2/16/2024 8:52:15 | 395 | 2 | Maintenance | 2 | =80+80.11.06-M1 | Manual mode | 11585 |
| 805049 | 2 | 2/16/2024 8:52:15 | 395 | 2 | Maintenance | 2 | =80+80.11.04-M1 | Manual mode | 11583 |
| 805048 | 2 | 2/16/2024 8:52:15 | 395 | 2 | Maintenance | 2 | =80+80.11.03-M1 | Manual mode | 11582 |
| 805050 | 2 | 2/16/2024 8:52:15 | 395 | 2 | Maintenance | 2 | =80+80.11.05-M1 | Manual mode | 11584 |
| 720669 | 2 | 2/16/2024 8:20:27 | 470 | 40 | Error | 1 | =72+72.04.71-WE1 | General error weighing scale | 8902 |

The powershell script looks like this:

```
$datasetAlg.Tables[0] |
    select -first 20|
    select MsgNr,State,DateTime,Ms,TimeDiff,Typename,Type,Text2,Text1,AlarmTag |
    Sort-Object -Property DateTime |
    Sort-Object -Property MsgNr -Unique |
    Export-CSV "D:\WinCC_Active_Messages_result.csv"
```

I need to have only the rows that contain the latest "State" (and other row contents) of all the "MsgNr" values. So to get the latest values I'm sorting them from newest to oldest. Than I want to keep all the rows where the first encounter of a "MsgNr" value is unique. That way I get the latest "State" (and other row contents) of all the "MsgNr" values.

The MsgNr values must stay sorted by DateTime and the result should have the first record of every unique MsgNr listed in that order. (So the latest records first)

`Sort-Object -Property MsgNr -Unique` does not seem to respect the order I sorted on with `Sort-Object -Property DateTime |`

Comment: well, of course. You are telling it to RE-order everything by MsgNr. SDo you need the DateTime\MsgNr couple being unique, or only MsgNr?   

in first case, just use `Sort-Object -Property DateTime, MsgNr -Unique`. Otherwise, just switch the Sorts: `Sort-Object -Property MgNr -Unique | Sort-Object -property Datetime`

Also: you might want to move `Select-Object -First 20` AFTER the sorts so you get the first 20 results out of the whole table, instead of manipulating the first 20 result unsorted

Comment: I need to have only the rows that contain the latest status of all the "MsgNr" values.
So to get the latest values I'm sorting them from newest to oldest.
Than I want to keep all the rows where the first encounter of a "MsgNr" value is unique.
That way I get the latest "Status" (and other row contents) of all the "MsgNr" values.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this `Sort-Object -Property DateTime | Sort-Object -Property MsgNr` will first sort the collection using `DateTime` property, then, re-sort the whole result against the property MsgNr. In the end, it would be equivalent to just doing `Sort-Object -Property MsgNr`.

If you want to sort something by multiple properties, you have to do it in the same `Sort-Object` cmdlet, separating the properties using a comma `,`. For descending order, you can use `-Descending` :

```
$datasetAlg.Tables[0] |
    select -first 20|
    select MsgNr,State,DateTime,Ms,TimeDiff,Typename,Type,Text2,Text1,AlarmTag |
    Sort-Object -Property DateTime,MsgNr -Unique -Descending |
    Export-CSV "D:\WinCC_Active_Messages_result.csv"
```

More informations can be found in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-7.4)

Comment: This doesn't result in having the latest status for the "MsgNr" value. 

As it provides all the rows where both the combination of "MsgNr" and "DateTime" are unique.
So to me it seems like there needs to be a solution to this where the `-Unique` only is for the "MsgNr" and where it doesn't alter the sortation on "DateTime".

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$datasetAlg.Tables[0] |
    Select-Object -Unique -Property MsgNr | 
    Foreach-Object {
        $datasetAlg.Tables[0]  | 
            Where-Object -Property MsgNr -eq $_.MsgNr |
            Sort-Object -Property DateTime -Descending | 
            Select-Object -First 1 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I Managed to get it working like this:

```
$Exportdataset = $datasetAlg.Tables[0] | 
  Group-Object -Property MsgNr |
      ForEach-Object {
        $LatestMsgNrStates = $_.Group |
          Sort-Object -Property DateTime, Ms -Descending |
            Select-Object -First 1
              [pscustomobject]@{
                MsgNr = $_.Name
                State = $LatestMsgNrStates.State
                DateTime = $LatestMsgNrStates.DateTime.AddHours(1)
                Ms = $LatestMsgNrStates.Ms
                TimeDiff = $LatestMsgNrStates.TimeDiff
                Typename = $LatestMsgNrStates.Typename
                Type = $LatestMsgNrStates.Type
                Text2 = $LatestMsgNrStates.Text2
                Text1 = $LatestMsgNrStates.Text1
                AlarmTag = $LatestMsgNrStates.AlarmTag
              }
      } | Where-Object State -lt 2 |
        Export-CSV -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation "D:\WinCC_Active_Scada_Messages.csv"
```